# "Kernel Restarting" problem with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to run my Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda Navigator). Everything is correct (I hope) because program actually run when I use just python.

The problem with "Kernel Restarting. The kernel for notebook.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically." appears when I try to execute this part of code:

```
df_loss_acc = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
df_loss = df_loss_acc[['loss', 'val_loss']]
df_loss.rename(columns={'loss': 'train', 'val_loss': 'validation'}, inplace=True)
df_acc = df_loss_acc[['accuracy', 'val_accuracy']]
df_acc.rename(columns={'accuracy': 'train', 'val_accuracy': 'validation'}, inplace=True)
df_loss.plot(title='Conv Model loss', figsize=(12, 8)).set(xlabel='Epoch', ylabel='Loss')
df_acc.plot(title='Conv Model Accuracy', figsize=(12, 8)).set(xlabel='Epoch', ylabel='Accuracy')
```

Before this every part of code was correctly executed.

I tried to reinstall NumPy library and some tips from other articles but it didn't help.

Comment: Hi mausor11, it could be a memory problem. Maybe your computer has just enough memory to perform the computation code before this snippet. Try to display your RAM used level (in Windows you can see it in Task Manager, with Ctrl + Maj + Esc). If your computer is at its limit, it means that you have to free some RAM before drawing plots. To do so, simply save your dataframe, close your notebook, open a new one, load the saved content in a dataframe and plot it. (simpler: `%store df_acc` in your nb, then close it, create a new one and do `%store -r df_acc`).

Comment: Also, try to comment all lines of your snippet but the first, and run your notebook and observe if it crashes. If not, uncomment the second line, then the third, etc, to see what line exactly makes it crash (this is complementary to monitor your RAM and processor in the Task Manager)

Comment: ```
df_loss.plot(title='Conv Model loss', figsize=(12, 8)).set(xlabel='Epoch', ylabel='Loss')
```
This is the line where kernel crashes.

Comment: How is the RAM just before the execution of this line?